# Tkinter .exe file doesn't open after using PyInstaller

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, windows-10, pyinstaller

I've got a basic Tkinter window (Just a title and logo), and wanted to try out/practice PyInstaller. However when I use try to open the .exe file nothing happens. I used the command: *pyinstaller test_script.py* (test_script is just the name of my file. I did this in the directory where the file is located)

I'm using windows 10 and python 3.7.3. I'll put my Tkinter code below, if it's any help, and also my spec file (I'm not sure if it'll be formatted correctly, I'm new to this site):

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

root.title("Test Application 1")
root.iconbitmap("favicon.ico")
root.geometry("700x500")

root.mainloop()


### --- Spec file --- ##


# -*- mode: python -*-

block_cipher = None


a = Analysis(['test_script.py'],
             pathex=['C:\\Users\\User\\Documents\\Python stuff\\Other 
apps\\Misc\\TestApplicationOne'],
             binaries=[],
             datas=[],
             hiddenimports=[],
             hookspath=[],
             runtime_hooks=[],
             excludes=[],
             win_no_prefer_redirects=False,
             win_private_assemblies=False,
             cipher=block_cipher,
             noarchive=False)
pyz = PYZ(a.pure, a.zipped_data,
             cipher=block_cipher)
exe = EXE(pyz,
          a.scripts,
          [],
          exclude_binaries=True,
          name='test_script',
          debug=False,
          bootloader_ignore_signals=False,
          strip=False,
          upx=True,
          console=True )
coll = COLLECT(exe,
               a.binaries,
               a.zipfiles,
               a.datas,
               strip=False,
               upx=True,
               name='test_script')
```

I get no errors or anything, the application just doesn't open. I've tried opening the .exe in both the dist and build folders. I've also deleted everything and started again, and still no luck. The application seems to open for a split second and then instantly close.

Comment: Run it from an already-open command prompt, so that you can see whatever error is being generated.

Comment: @jasonharper I just did that, and the same thing happens - the window opens for a split second (not long enough to even see it, I can only see the blue bar in the taskbar appear) and then it instantly disappears

Comment: No messages appeared in the command window you ran it from?  My guess is that `favicon.ico` is not being found, but that would definitely produce an error message.

Comment: from the looks of things here, I second what @jasonharper said. It looks like it is not able to find the icon. You can simply remove `root.iconbitmap("favicon.ico")` and then convert to an .exe and see if that fixes it.

Comment: @probat I just tried removing the `root.iconbitmap("favicon.ico")` and the problem is still persisting.

Comment: @jasonharper is correct, you run it from command prompt and there you can see the error. Most probably, the error is in the code or associated files and not in the .exe. I had same problem and on cmd it showed that I made an import of file, but that file was not present in "dist" folder. Yours might be different error but it will be shown in cmd and you can get that solved.

Answer (score 1):

try to use the following code pyinstaller -F -w --icon=favicon.ico test_script.py , you might also use the debug option to get a verbose output of what is happening and where the error is

Comment: Hi Hitch, thanks for answering! When you answer a question, it's important to explain it thoroughly rather than just showing a code sample. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65243997/edit) your answer to add more details.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was the icon. Removing the `root.iconbitmap()` line helped.